# How to set up atom / juno to run julia?

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I'm trying to set up Atom/Juno to run Julia so that it looks like the screen grab on this website - it looks exactly like what I want. http://junolab.org/

I have downloaded and installed Julia and Atom.  On Atom I have installed packages uber-juno, julia-client and language-julia.

When trying to start Julia in Atom, I get the following error:

Error installing Atom.jl package
Go to the Packages → Julia → Open Terminal menu and
run `Pkg.add("Atom")` in Julia, then try again.
If you still see an issue, please report it to:
    julia-users@googlegroups.com

When I go to the terminal and type 'Pkg.add("Atom") I get the following error:

```
julia> Pkg.add("Atom")
INFO: Initializing package repository C:\Users\BRB\.julia\v0.5
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
ERROR: ArgumentError: 'C:\Users\BRB\.julia\v0.5\REQUIRE' exists. `remove_destination=true` is required to remove 'C:\Users\BRB\.julia\v0.5\REQUIRE' before moving.
 in #checkfor_mv_cp_cptree#8(::Bool, ::Function, ::String, ::String, ::String) at .\file.jl:147
 in (::Base.Filesystem.#kw##checkfor_mv_cp_cptree)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.Filesystem.#checkfor_mv_cp_cptree, ::String, ::String, ::String) at .\<missing>:0
 in #mv#11 at .\file.jl:184 [inlined]
 in mv at .\file.jl:184 [inlined]
 in init(::String, ::String) at .\pkg\dir.jl:58
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at .\pkg\dir.jl:28
 in add(::String) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:100
```

I have no idea what to do next.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you may be interested in just using [JuliaPro](https://juliacomputing.com/products/juliapro.html) (personal edition)

Comment: First off, uber-juno is enough and it would install other required packages like julia-client, latex-completion, ... Secondly have you tried running `Pkg.add("Atom") in REPL?` Anyway this might be relevant: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19873

Comment: @Tascos.  Thank you, I will definitely take a look at JuliaPro

Comment: @A. Yazdiha.  Yes, I have tried running Pkg.add("Atom") in REPL and I get the above error.  I did look at the github link but I'm sorry, I don't know what I should do based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a corrupt `.julia` directory. Delete `C:\Users\BRB\.julia` completely and try again.

Comment: Maybe try to remove only `'C:\Users\BRB\.julia\v0.5\REQUIRE'` before...